# Laravel "Bootstrapper" module ; Cannot pass attribute array

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Using Laravel and the "Bootstrapper" module ("patricktalmadge/bootstrapper").

Have searched the web and SO over and cannot find the correct way to pass optional attributes to things like "buttons".

For example:

```
$iconRemove = Button::primary([
                'data-id' => $root->id
                ])
                ->prependIcon(Icon::remove());
```

Obviously the variable `$root->id` would be a record number, so what I am trying to pass would end up looking somehting like:

```
$iconRemove = Button::primary([
                'data-id' => 2
                ])
                ->prependIcon(Icon::remove());
```

This seems like this should be possible, but I can find no comparable example.

Instead, I get the error

> An exception of type ErrorException was thrown with the message: Array
>   to string conversion

Anyone no the best practice for solving this problem using this module or a better practice / module for generating Twitter Bootstrap components in Laravel that would enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I don't know the package* but from scanning the source quickly I can see that the `Button::primary` method takes only one parameter. Which is the label of the button.

You can add other attributes though, by using `addAttributes()` (or `withAttributes()`, add is an alias)

```
Button::primary('Text')
            ->addAttributes([
                'data-id' => $root->id
            ])
            ->prependIcon(Icon::remove());
```

Comment: That fixed it.  I called myself poring over the source, but I never glommed onto that.  Wonderful.  Hopefully this helps someone else as as I.I

Comment: You're welcome. If you're interested in my search process, I just searched for the Button class. After I saw that `primary` only takes one string as argument I searched the whole class for `attributes` and baaam! found :)